# Parse JSON with 2 objects before an array

Tags: java, android, json

I'm currently trying to parse some JSON in my android application but I keep getting an error saying "No value for users"

This is the current code I am using:

```
JSONObject parentObject = new JSONObject(finalJSON);

            JSONObject childObject = new JSONObject(String.valueOf(parentObject));

            JSONArray parentArray = childObject.getJSONArray("users");

            JSONObject finalObject = parentArray.getJSONObject(0);

            String userName = finalObject.getString("username");

            String profileLink = finalObject.getString("profileimage");

            Log.d("JSON", String.valueOf(finalObject));

            return profileimage+ " - " + profileLink ;
```

and here is my JSON:

```
{
"reply": {
    "users": [
        {
            "userid": "001",
            "loggedIn": 1,
            "username": "joe.bloggs",
            "profileimage": "http://127.0.0.1/joebloggs.png",
            "realname": "Joe Bloggs",
        }
    ]

   }
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You forgot the `reply` level.

Here is what you should do.

```
JSONObject parentObject = new JSONObject(finalJSON);


JSONArray userArray = parentObject
                .getJSONObject("reply")
                .getJSONArray("users");

JSONObject finalObject = userArray.getJSONObject(0);
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, so I've just tried that but it is asking me to wrap it as an integer?

Comment: Nevermind, I tried to do .getJSONArray("reply").getJSONArray("users").

Answer (score 0):

you can't take new object for object inside object.

you have to do this for parse object inside object.

```
JSONObject object1 =  new JSONObject(finalJSON);

JSONObject object2 =  object1.getJSONObject("reply");

JSONArray jsonArray = object2.getJSONArray("users");

JSONObject object3 =  jsonArray.getJSONObject(0);
```

Answer (score 0):

try the following:

```
JSONObject root = null;
try {
    root = new JSONObject("reply");
    JSONArray childArray = root.getJSONArray("users");
    String userName = childArray.getString(0);
    .
    .
    .
} catch (JSONException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```